# Top-down, non-recursive merger

Tags: java, recursion

I'm meant to give a brief presentation on a rather large piece of code where I illustrate a specific function non-recursively, to make a point. I believe I have identified the appropriate part of the code,

```
public static void sort(Comparable[] a) {
        Comparable[] aux = new Comparable[a.length];
        sort(a, aux, 0, a.length-1);
        assert isSorted(a);
```

as the part of the code that needs to be changed. What I am not seeing is how I can actually make it non-recursive. I know I will need to remove the a.length-1 part, but I don't know with what. A colleague mentioned this is harder than it seems, as I need to preserve the order of the original code. I didn't exactly know what he meant, but I felt it couldn't hurt to include that bit of info.

EDIT: I found this in the code:

// mergesort a[lo..hi] using auxiliary array aux[lo..hi]

```
private static void sort(Comparable[] a, Comparable[] aux, int lo, int hi) {
    if (hi <= lo) return;
    int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
    sort(a, aux, lo, mid);
    sort(a, aux, mid + 1, hi);
    merge(a, aux, lo, mid, hi);
}
```

However, I am supposed to be focusing on `public static void sort(Comparable[] a)`
according to my prompt. Specifically, I am supposed to replace that function with a new non-recursive function.

EDIT 2: Ok, if the second function I have is the recursive one, how can I change it? I thought that when I see something along the lines of (N-1), that's what signified the recursion. But I don't see that in the second function.

EDIT 3: The help thus far has been great. I tried incorporating the answer given to me below, and I've run into this problem at compile time:

```
File: /Users/spencer/Downloads/MergeTDNonrecursive.java  [line: 75]
Error: /Users/spencer/Downloads/MergeTDNonrecursive.java:75: possible loss of precision
found   : long
required: int
```

That loss of precision bit is where I'm lost, I've never seen that before. The code that appears to be the source of that error is:

```
if (rend > num) rend = num;
```

Another error I have is

```
File: /Users/spencer/Downloads/MergeTDNonrecursive.java  [line: 106]
Error: /Users/spencer/Downloads/MergeTDNonrecursive.java:106: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method sort(java.lang.Comparable[],java.lang.Comparable[],int,int)
location: class MergeTDNonrecursive
```

for the code:`sort(a, aux, 0, a.length-1);`

I also got 2 warnings when I compiled, but I think they might resolve themselves once I've got these bases covered. Specifically, the terms 'long' and 'symbol' are lost on me, in each error respectively.

Comment: This is the wrong function. Try to find something like `sort(Comparable[], Comparable[], Integer, Integer)` instead.

Comment: your first function sort(Comparable[]), is not recursive. The second one is

Comment: recursion is signified by the fact that a function is calling itself, not that there is some N-1. `boolean abc() { return abc(); }` This function is also recursive.

Comment: The thing that makes a function recursive is that it calls itself. Any *good*  recursive function will work on a smaller subset of the problem in each recursive call, which is exactly what your second `sort` function does by working on smaller arrays in each call.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood you would like to have non recoursive merge sort. Look on it and adapt it to your code.

```
float a[50000000],b[50000000];
void mergesort (long num)
{
    int rght, wid, rend;
    int i,j,m,t;

    for (int k=1; k < num; k *= 2 ) {       
        for (int left=0; left+k < num; left += k*2 ) {
            rght = left + k;        
            rend = rght + k;
            if (rend > num) rend = num; 
            m = left; i = left; j = rght; 
            while (i < rght && j < rend) { 
                if (a[i] <= a[j]) {         
                    b[m] = a[i]; i++;
                } else {
                    b[m] = a[j]; j++;
                }
                m++;
            }
            while (i < rght) { 
                b[m]=a[i]; 
                i++; m++;
            }
            while (j < rend) { 
                b[m]=a[j]; 
                j++; m++;
            }
            for (m=left; m < rend; m++) { 
                a[m] = b[m]; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```